# Add calendar of colleague on Office 365

Tags: calendar, office365

I'm trying to view the calendar of my colleague on Office 365 using my web browser. His calendar is set to share busy/free within the organization. The official documentation I can find tells me to add the calendar "From Directory". However, I don't have any "From Directory" option. I've attached here a screenshot from the documentation as well as a view of my interface.

The one colleague that can be seen shared his calendar with me specifically, not just "within the organization".

[image: The documentation wants me to add "From Directory"]
[image: My interface does not have any "From Directory" option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click **Your calendars**, select **Open calendar**.

[image]

Then you can see the "**From directory**", type your colleague name who share calendar to you and search directory, click Open to add the calendar.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue. I had to search for the user in the top search bar. Then I found two ways to add her calendar.

1. The first was in the search results drop down. At the right there was an icon of a
   calendar. Clicking that adds the calendar.
2. The second was after choosing the user, there was an Add Calendar right under the name of the user.

[image]